# Merge pairs that share one element in common

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, vector, set

I have the following data structure:

```
set< pair<int, int> > data;
data = {<1, 1> ; <3, 2> ; <5, 5> ; <5, 4> ; <4, 2>, <1, 8>, <9, 9> }
```

I would like to merge pairs which contain at least one common element and store the result in a vector of sets.

```
vector< set<int> > result;
result = [ {1, 8} ; {2, 3, 4, 5} ; {9} ]
```

I know that there is a set_union in `<algorithm>` but how can we compute the "union" of pairs? Thanks!

Comment: why {1,8} and {2,3,4,5} are in result? Can you please explain?

Comment: 1 appears with 8 so we merge them, 3 appears with 2 wich appears with 4 which appears with 5 so we merge them, etc.

Comment: Have a look to [Connected_component](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_%28graph_theory%29) and more specificly to [Disjoint-set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure)

Comment: I think the problem could be transformed into something like graph searching algorithm. Your task is to search minimum number of subgraphs such that all nodes are covered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

typedef std::set<std::pair<int,int> > SetOfPair;
```

and:

```
struct pair_equal : std::unary_function< std::pair<int,int>, bool> {
    pair_equal(const int &idx) : idx_(idx) {}
    bool operator()(const std::pair<int,int> &arg) const { return 
                             ( arg.first == idx_) || ( arg.second == idx_); }
    const int &idx_;
};

std::set<int> connected_component( SetOfPair& sp) {
    std::vector<int> componentIndices;
    componentIndices.push_back( (*(sp.begin())).first);
    componentIndices.push_back( (*(sp.begin())).second);
    int indexCount = 2;
    int currIdx = 0;

    SetOfPair::const_iterator it;
    while ( currIdx < indexCount) {
        while ( ( it = std::find_if( sp.begin(), sp.end(), pair_equal( 
                                 componentIndices[ currIdx]))) != sp.end()) {
            /* new reachable index connected to this component found */
            int newIdx = ( componentIndices[ currIdx] == 
                                    (*it).first? (*it).second : (*it).first);
            /* insert if not present already */
            if ( std::find( componentIndices.begin(), 
                 componentIndices.end(), newIdx) == componentIndices.end()) {
                componentIndices.push_back( newIdx);
                ++indexCount;
            }
            sp.erase( it);
        }
        ++currIdx;
    }
    return std::set<int>( componentIndices.begin(), componentIndices.end());
}
```

and:

```
int make_connected_components( SetOfPair sp, 
                          std::vector<std::set<int> >& result) {
    int componentCount = 0;
    while( !sp.empty()) {
        std::set<int> component = connected_component( sp);
        result.push_back( component);
        ++componentCount;
    }
    return componentCount;
}
```

usage:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    SetOfPair sp;
    sp.insert( std::make_pair<int, int>( 1, 1));
    sp.insert( std::make_pair<int, int>( 3, 2));
    sp.insert( std::make_pair<int, int>( 5, 5));
    sp.insert( std::make_pair<int, int>( 5, 4));
    sp.insert( std::make_pair<int, int>( 4, 2));
    sp.insert( std::make_pair<int, int>( 1, 8));
    sp.insert( std::make_pair<int, int>( 9, 9));

    std::vector<std::set<int> > components;
    int numberOfComponents = make_connected_components( sp, components);

    /* results */
    std::cout << "numberOfComponents:" << numberOfComponents << std::endl;
    std::vector<std::set<int> >::iterator it = components.begin();
    while ( it != components.end()) {
        std::copy( (*it).begin(), (*it).end(), 
                             std::ostream_iterator<int>( std::cout, ":"));
        std::cout << std::endl;
        ++it;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

numberOfComponents:3

1:8:

2:3:4:5:

9:

RUN SUCCESSFUL (total time: 61ms)

[compiled online](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7b5e4c2ea0603429)

Comment: not a problem at all, this is of course not fastest what we can get - you can optimize if necessary

Answer (score 1):

As Jarod42 points out, you want the connected components of the graph defined by your edge list. Here's how to get those using the STL.

1. Construct an *adjacency list*: a `map<int, set<int> >` that maps each integer to the set of integers with which it co-occurs in a pair. This can be done with one iteration through the vector of pairs, adding `.second` to `.first`'s set and `.first` to `.second`'s.
2. Traverse the adjacency list depth-first. This is somewhat more complicated. Initialize the `vector<set<int> >`. Keep a `set<int>`, initially empty, of integers that have been processed. Loop through the entries of the adjacency list. For each integer key that does not appear in the processed set, construct the next component as follows and push it back onto the vector, then union-update the set of processed integers with the component.
3. Initialize a `stack<int>` with the integer key from 2. Initialize an empty `set<int>`, the current connected component. While the stack is not empty, grab its top integer and pop it. If this integer does not appear in the component, then do the following. Insert the integer into the component, then look it up in the adjacency list and push all of its neighbors onto the stack.